# Adding controls to GroupBox during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a GroupBox, add a Grid (or StackPanel) to it then put some TextBlocks on it, all during runtime. This is what i've tried

```
GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
Grid grid1 = new Grid();

groupBox1.Width = 85;
groupBox1.Height = 60;
grid1.Height =  85;
grid1.Width =  60;

groupBox1.Content = grid1.Children.Add(textBlock1);
groupBox1.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 0, 0);

mainWindow.canvas.Children.Add(groupBox1);
```

But all I get is a groupbox with a thick white border with nothing in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see a [Grid.Children.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.add.aspx) returns an `int` and that's not what you want to set the content of the `groupBox1` to.

An untested idea from me as a non WPF expert is to set the grid as the Content of your groupbox.

```
grid1.Children.Add(textBlock1);
groupBox1.Content = grid1;
```

Comment: Ah, I see but now I suppose my question is how do I go about placing a gird inside a groupbox during runtime?

Comment: Just tried groupBox1.Content = grid1 and it seems to have worked. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

For simple checkboxes i used this code :

```
var container = new FlowLayoutPanel
{
     FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
     Dock = DockStyle.Fill
 };
 myGroupBox.Controls.Add(container);
 foreach (var myText in textList)
 {
     var checkBox = new CheckBox
     {
         Text = myText

     };
     container.Controls.Add(checkBox);
 }
```

Of course the foreach statement is just for the example :)